# Get the location with the locationmanager inside Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, locationmanager

As the title mentoioned ,trying to get the location inside async task but ,so far I have failed.I am getting null exception with the latitute and longtitude
Here is the my codes.

```
public class AsyncLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, MyLocation> {

        private Context _cntx=null; 
        AsyncLocation(Context cntx){

            _cntx= cntx;
        }

        public AsyncResponse delegate;
        MyLocation myLocation =null;

        public LocationManager mLocationManager;

        @Override
        protected MyLocation doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            Log.d("GtLocation", "ICERDE");
             mLocationManager = (LocationManager)_cntx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             Location location =  mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
           double  latitude = location.getLatitude();
           double  longitude = location.getLongitude();
             Log.d("onPreExecute", "ICERDE");
            MyLocation mylc= new MyLocation();
            mylc.Lat=latitude;
            mylc.Lng=longitude;

            return mylc;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MyLocation rsp) {

            Log.d("onPostExecute", "ICERDE");
                Log.d("vvvvresponse", rsp.toString());

                Toast.makeText(_cntx,
                        "LATITUDE :" + rsp.Lat + " LONGITUDE :" + rsp.Lng,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // delegate.processFinish(rsp);
                super.onPostExecute(rsp);

    }
    }
```

Any help appriciated ,thank you

Comment: pls explain me why down vote,so that I can fix my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done something thats similar to this.
Ive solved this problem with intitializing the Location Manager in OnCreate() Method and call in the OnPostExecute() method another method which saves my Current Position to a Variable of type Location.

```
     curPos = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

After that you can get the LatLng coords over curPos.getLatitude()

Hope it helped u a bit